# There are many jobs are in my Database. how can i differentiate which is DBMS_JOB and DBMS_scheduler, do we any query to filter only DBMS_JOB

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-administration

There are many jobs are in my Database. how can i differentiate  which is DBMS_JOB and DBMS_scheduler, do we any query to filter only  DBMS_JOB

Comment: Have a look at view `ALL_JOBS` and `ALL_SCHEDULER_JOBS`

Comment: This doesn't differentiate between the two when looking at either all_scheduler_jobs or all_objects

Answer (score 1):

Any legacy job defined using dbms_job and visible in dba_jobs will also appear as a scheduler job in dba_scheduler_jobs. That's because Oracle now implements *all* jobs as the newer scheduler job type. The older job interface is now merely a scaled-down wrapper around the new job types, for backward compatibility.

You can differentiate between them by the job name. Legacy jobs show up in dba_scheduler_jobs with names like "DBMS_JOB$_29". The number suffix is the job id from dba_jobs, for the particular owner in question.